# reading line in bufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

From the javadoc

```
public String readLine()
            throws IOException

Read a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
```

I have following kind of text :

```
Now the earth was formless and empty.  Darkness was on the surface
of the deep.  God's Spirit was hovering over the surface
of the waters.
```

I am reading lines as:

```
 while(buffer.readline() != null){
       }
```

But, the problem is it is considering a line for string upto before newline.But i would like to consider line when string ends with `.`. How would i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read a character at a time, and copy the data to a StringBuilder

```
Reader reader = ...;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int ch;
while((ch = reader.read()) >= 0) {
    if(ch == '.') break;
    sb.append((char) ch);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and set your own delimiter using [`useDelimiter(Pattern)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29).

Note that the input delimiter is a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), so you will need to provide the regex `\.` (you need to break the special meaning of the character `.` in regex)

Answer (score 4):

- Use a `java.util.Scanner` instead of a buffered reader, and set the delimiter to `"\\."` with `Scanner.useDelimiter()`.
  (but be aware that the delimiter is consumed, so you'll have to add it again!)
- or read the raw string and split it on each `.`

Answer (score 4):

You could split the whole text by every `.`:

```
String text = "Your test.";
String[] lines = text.split("\\.");
```

After you split the text you get an array of lines. You could also use a regex if you want more control, e.g. to split the text also by `:` or `;`. Just google it.

PS.: Perhaps you have to remove the new line characters first with something like:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\n", "");
```